# combine 2 lists of list to list of tuples

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to combine to different nested list into a list of tuples (x,y)
where x comes from the first nested list and y from the second nested list.

```
nested_list1 = [[1, 2, 3],[3],[0, 3],[1]]
nested_list2 = [[.0833, .0833, .0833], [.2], [.175, .175], [.2]]
```

when you combine them it should be:

```
result = [(1,.0833), (2,.0833), (3,.0833), (3,.2), (0,.175), (3,.175), (1,.2)]
```

my approach is that i need to iterate through the list of lists and join them 1 at a time.
I know to iterate through 1 nested list like so:

```
for list in nested_list1:
    for number in list:
        print(number)
```

but I can't iterate through 2 nested list at the same time.

```
for list, list in zip(nested_list1, nested_list2):
    for number, prob in zip(list,list):
        print(tuple(number, prob)) #will not work
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a double [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) through lists:

```
lst1 = [[1, 2, 3],[3],[0, 3],[1]]
lst2 = [[.0833, .0833, .0833], [.2], [.175, .175], [.2]]

print([(u, v) for x, y in zip(lst1, lst2) for u, v in zip(x, y)])
```

Or use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten list and `zip`:

```
from itertools import chain

lst1 = [[1, 2, 3],[3],[0, 3],[1]]
lst2 = [[.0833, .0833, .0833], [.2], [.175, .175], [.2]]

print(list(zip(chain.from_iterable(lst1), chain.from_iterable(lst2))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> nested_list1 = [[1, 2, 3],[3],[0, 3],[1]]
>>> nested_list2 = [[.0833, .0833, .0833], [.2], [.175, .175], [.2]]
>>> import itertools
>>> res = list(zip(itertools.chain.from_iterable(nested_list1), itertools.chain.from_iterable(nested_list2)))
>>> res
[(1, 0.0833), (2, 0.0833), (3, 0.0833), (3, 0.2), (0, 0.175), (3, 0.175), (1, 0.2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten your lists and then pass to `zip()`:

```
list1 = [item for sublist in nested_list1 for item in sublist]
list2 = [item for sublist in nested_list2 for item in sublist]
final = list(zip(list1, list2))
```

Yields:

```
[(1, 0.0833), (2, 0.0833), (3, 0.0833), (3, 0.2), (0, 0.175), (3, 0.175), (1, 0.2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
[result.extend(list(zip(x, y))) for x in nested_list1 for y in nested_list2]
print(result)
```

Comment: This will return a list of list instead of a single list.

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors in your code:

1. You shadow built-in `list` twice and in a way that you can't differentiate between two variables. Don't do this.
2. You use `tuple(x, y)` to create a `tuple` form 2 variables. This is incorrect, as `tuple` takes one argument only. To construct a tuple of two variables just use syntax `(x, y)`.

So this will work:

```
for L1, L2 in zip(nested_list1, nested_list2):
    for number, prob in zip(L1, L2):
        print((number, prob))
```

More idiomatic would be to flatten your nested lists; for example, via [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

res = list(zip(chain.from_iterable(nested_list1),
               chain.from_iterable(nested_list2)))

[(1, 0.0833), (2, 0.0833), (3, 0.0833), (3, 0.2), (0, 0.175), (3, 0.175), (1, 0.2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This one liner will achieve what you want.

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [[(i, j) for i, j in zip(x,y)] for x, y in zip(nested_list1, nested_list2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert both the nested lists into full lists and then use zip. Sample code below:

```
>>> nested_list1 = [[1, 2, 3],[3],[0, 3],[1]]
>>> nested_list2 = [[.0833, .0833, .0833], [.2], [.175, .175], [.2]]
>>> new_list1 = [x for val in nested_list1 for x in val]
>>> new_list2 = [x for val in nested_list2 for x in val]
>>> print new_list1
[1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 3, 1]
>>> print new_list2
[0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.2, 0.175, 0.175, 0.2]
>>> new_val = zip(new_list1, new_list2)
>>> print new_val
[(1, 0.0833), (2, 0.0833), (3, 0.0833), (3, 0.2), (0, 0.175), (3, 0.175), (1, 0.2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two times zip and flatten the list

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,[(zip(i,j)) for i,j in zip(nested_list1,nested_list2)])
```

You can flatten using `chain` as well

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*[(zip(i,j)) for i,j in zip(nested_list1,nested_list2)]))
```

output

```
[(1, 0.0833), (2, 0.0833), (3, 0.0833), (3, 0.2), (0, 0.175), (3, 0.175), (1, 0.2)]
```